# Estou com um problema ao carregar um campo usando uma função no ADVPL

Tags: sql-server, advpl

Preciso carregar o campo CK_XLOTE digitando o codigo do produto no campo CK_PRODUTO, estou gerando uma função pra realizar este procedimento, mas não esta retornando o lote no campo.Alguém pode me ajudar.

Segue o codigo

```
#INCLUDE 'PROTHEUS.CH'
#INCLUDE 'PARMTYPE.CH'

User Function TESTE()

//MsgAlert(M->CK_PRODUTO)

Local cQuery        := ""
Local cLote         := ""

cQuery := " SELECT  TOP 1 "
cQuery += "         SB8.B8_LOTECTL, "
cQuery += "         SB8.B8_DTVALID "
cQuery += " FROM    " + RetSQLName("SB8") + "   AS SB8 "
cQuery += " WHERE   SB8.B8_FILIAL               = '" + xFilial("SB8") + "' "
cQuery += " AND     SB8.B8_LOCAL                = '01' "
cQuery += " AND     SB8.B8_DTVALID              > GETDATE() "
cQuery += " AND     SB8.B8_SALDO                > SB8.B8_EMPENHO "
cQuery += " AND     SB8.B8_PRODUTO              = '" + M->CK_PRODUTO + "' "
cQuery += " AND     SB8.D_E_L_E_T_              = '' "
cQuery += " ORDER BY SB8.B8_DTVALID "

If SELECT("SQL") > 0    
    dbSelectArea("SQL")     
    dbCloseArea()       
EndIf 

cQuery := ChangeQuery(cQuery)                                                              
dbUseArea(.T., 'TOPCONN', TCGENQRY(,,cQuery),"SQL", .F., .T.)       
dbSelectArea("SQL")

If SQL->(!EOF())

    cLote := SQL->B8_LOTECTL

EndIf

return(cLote)
```

Segue a configuração do gatilho
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma dica, não use alias de tabela começando com S, principalmente com 3 letras.. Pois é utilizado pelas tabelas padrões, tente utilizar um GetNextAlias() para determinar o alias e veja se funciona...

Comment: Vlw obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Vlw obrigado pela ajuda. Agora vc pode me tirar uma duvida,esta minha função e pra carregar um campo que a query esta trazendo, agora minha duvida é, se nesta mesma query, eu traga dois campos como resultado, pra eu preencher dois campos no sistema e necessário criar duas funções uma pra cada gatilho do campo especifico no contra domínio.

Answer (score 3):

Provavelmente a Query não está trazendo nenhum registro, devido a montagem de uma ou duas condições na Query:

```
cQuery += " AND     SB8.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' "
```

Ao comparar o campo SB8.D_E_L_E_T_, compare-o com uma string com um espaço em branco `(' ')` ao invés de uma string vazia `('')`. O banco de dados entende que uma string vazia sem espaços representa o valor NULL -- e nenhum registro vai atender a esta condição.

```
cQuery += " AND     SB8.B8_DTVALID              > GETDATE() "
```

Ao comparar o campo B8_VALID na Query, lembre-se que um campo DATA em AdvPL é gravado no banco de dados como um varchar(8), no formato AAAAMMDD. Logo, certifique-se que esta comparação entre a data em formato caractere e a função GetDate() realmente aceita o formato atual, ou se nao é necessário fazer um CAST() do campo B8_VALID ou mesmo um CAST() da GETDATE() para retornar uma string no formato adequado para comparação.

Comment: Use o botão `{ }` ou control K para formatar trechos de código. Linhas de código podem ser formatadas com 4 espaços em branco no começo, e trechos inline delimitando com backtick `. Mais ajuda [aqui](/editing-help)

Comment: Muito grato !!! Estou editando minha resposta :)